# How to update label text in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

In my vb.net winform application, on click of start button the label1.text should be "process started" then some filesaving method will run after finish that method the label1.text should change to "file saved".

```
 Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click

    lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red
    lblStatus.Text = "Saving to File"

     'Get the values and write to xls
             Trigger()
             SaveXls()

     lblStatus.Text = "File Saved"
     lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Green
End Sub
```

the initial status of label "saving to file" is not comingup. after the Trigger method  finished, the status of the label is changing to "File saved"

Any suggestions please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [delay text to speech until after label.text updates in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725067/delay-text-to-speech-until-after-label-text-updates-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the Refresh() method of the label. Using Application.DoEvents has side effects and should be used carefully (this is not the appropriate use for it).

Comment: To explain further: when you change something on a control, the control is flagged for repainting.  The repainting doesn't happen until all other code has finished running.  This prevents countless repaints when several controls are changed in one lump of code, or one control is changed in several ways.  Calling `Control.Refresh()` forces it to repaint now.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to the other two answers (and my preference) would be to use [**Background Worker**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to execute `Trigger()` and `SaveXls()`.

Your code will look something like:

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click

    lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red
    lblStatus.Text = "Saving to File"

    If backgroundWorker1.IsBusy <> True Then
        ' Start the asynchronous operation.
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub backgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles backgroundWorker1.DoWork
     'Get the values and write to xls
             Trigger()
             SaveXls()
End Sub

Private Sub backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Cancelled = True Then
        lblStatus.Text = "Canceled!"
        lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Black
    ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
        lblStatus.Text = "Error: " & e.Error.Message
    Else
        lblStatus.Text = "File Saved"
        lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Green
    End If
End Sub
```

Using Background Worker will also leave your form responsive while the background operation is happening instead of freezing it.

Answer (score 1):

after set the label text initially, refresh the form using form1.refresh(). Then Trigger() and SaveXls() functions will execute and finally change the label text to "filesaved".

Thanks for all ur replies and efforts

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to quit blocking your code for a moment after you update your lblStatus label.  You can try putting an `Application.DoEvents` after your first label update.  Otherwise, your form will wait to refresh until your entire code block has finished executing.  `Application.DoEvents` will suspend your current thread, process the windows messages, and then continue executing once finished.