# Put A textbox value in a Label from another form

Tags: vb.net

I have Two Forms 
In The First Form I Have A Textbox Called TB1 An A String Called S1
In The Second Form I Have A Label Called L1
I Declared them publicly in a module

```
 Module M1
Public L1 As New Label
Public TB1 As new Textbox
Public S1 As new String
End Module
/../
'in the First form
S1=TextBox1.text
'in the second form
L1.text=S1
```

But I Get this error "System.NullReferenceException" on the first Label L1 
Any ideas why i'm getting this error

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848495/how-to-update-label-text-in-vb-net

Comment: The form would have to refresh

Comment: I didn't get it Can  u please clarify more and keep it as simple as possible

Comment: Can u suggest the simplest method 
Like Make The Label Public Or Something like that
I am Just a beginner

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

On Form1 in the event calling Form2, Add:

```
Form2.L1.Text = TextBox1.text
Form2.Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put them in a module like that; nothing will see them.

In addition, there's no way to see how this code is flowing.

To do a simple exercise:

Draw first form - form1 with Textbox1 on it.

Make the first form startup form (it will be by default in new winforms project)

Draw 2nd form - form2 with Label1 on it.

Put a button on the first form

Double click the button

In the handler put this code:

```
Sub Button1_Click (etc...
    dim Form2Instance as new Form2
    Form2Instance.Label1.Caption = Textbox1.text
    Form2Instance.ShowDialog
End Sub
```

You can put a textbox on form2 and read the results in form1 the same way.

You can tell if the user OK'd (not canceled) form2 like this:

```
if Form2Instance.ShowDialog() = DialogResults.OK then 
    ' only do this code if they HIT OK
```

I suggest maybe hitting youtube or pluralsite and watching a 'winforms for beginners' video, if such a thing exists. There are a lot of traps and pitfalls that you will run into hacking away on your own, that will be explained to before hand if you learn the basics. This is especially true if you've only done web programming or are just learning programming.